Preconditioner for "Generalized stokes" problem
Let $\mu>0$.  For the Stokes problem,
\begin{align}
-\mu \Delta u + \nabla p &= f
\\
\nabla \cdot u & = 0
\\
u&= 0 \text{ on } \partial \Omega,
\end{align}
after discretization (say, using some inf-sup stable finite element) we arrive at the saddle-point block system
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A & B^T
\\
B & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
In this case, a decent block preconditoner is
\begin{equation}
P =
\begin{bmatrix}
\widetilde{A} & 0
\\
0 & \widetilde{S}
\end{bmatrix} 
,
\label{pre1}
\end{equation}
where $\widetilde{A}$ is some preconditioner for $A$ (few multigrid cycles for $A$) and $\widetilde{S}$ is some preconditioner for the Schur complement $BA^{-1}B^T$ (I use the pressure mass matrix which is spectrally similar to the Schur complement).
Can we do something similar for the "generalized" Stokes problem?  Let $\rho>0$ be some scalar function (not necessarily constant throughout $\Omega$). The generalized Stokes problem is
\begin{align}
-\mu \Delta u + \rho u+ \nabla p &= f
\\
\nabla \cdot u & = 0
\\
u&= 0 \text{ on } \partial \Omega.
\end{align}
When I use the block-diagonal preconditioner for the generalized Stokes problem and use the pressure mass matrix for $\widetilde{S}$, the precondtioner+GMRES no longer works well; particularly if $\rho$ is non-constant over $\Omega$. The pressure mass matrix is not spectrally equivalent to the Schur complement $BA^{-1}B^T$.
I've seen the "reasoning" $B\approx -div$, $B^T\approx grad$, $A\approx -\Delta$, so $-div(-\Delta)^{-1}grad=-div (grad) (-\Delta)^{-1}=Id$, but this doesn't seem well founded for the (generalized) Stokes problem. Is it possible to find a preconditioner spectrally equivalent to $\widetilde{S}$ that is related to a discretization of some pressure operator?
